# javascript button to download a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, download

I want to download a JSON(or XML) file by pressing a button. In HTML I define:

```
<a id="exportJSON" onclick="exportJson()" class="btn"><i class="icon-download"></i> export json</a>
```

In JavaScipt I have following code:

```
function exportJson() {
   var obj = {a: 123, b: "4 5 6"};
   var data = "text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj));
   // what to return in order to show download window?
}
```

I found a [very nice answer in Stackoveflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721439/download-json-object-as-a-file-from-browser), but I fail to adjust it into my problem, mainly show the download window. I do not want to create another link somewhere in the page (like done in above mentioned answer, just directly show download window).

Comment: Try changing the mime type to `application/json`

Comment: It writes into the file: {"error": "Please use POST request"}. This is wrong!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/2k4LtaLw/5/

Change your a to this

```
<a id="exportJSON" onclick="exportJson(this);" class="btn"><i class="icon-download"></i> export json</a>
```

The function

```
function exportJson(el) {

    var obj = {
        a: 123,
        b: "4 5 6"
    };
    var data = "text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj));
    // what to return in order to show download window?

    el.setAttribute("href", "data:"+data);
    el.setAttribute("download", "data.json");    
}
```

Comment: It downloads the whole HTML file, but not the JSON file.

Comment: @Bob I have updated the answer :) Now it works as it should, it downloads the json file :)

Comment: Would be nice to have a version that works with `<button>` as well...

Comment: Err... I guess it does, if I just wrap the `<button>` in the `<a>` tag... still, might be nice to have a version that doesn't require that, if that's reasonably feasible.