# Download Object As Formatted JSON File

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I followed [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721439/download-json-object-as-a-file-from-browser) to download a JSON object from the browser. This is what my code looks like:

```js
var json = this.getEditorJSON();

var data = "text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(json));
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'data:' + data;
a.download = 'resume.json';
a.innerHTML = 'download JSON';

var container = document.getElementById('container');
container.appendChild(a);
a.click();

a.remove();
```

But this gives me a single line file that is hard to read. Is there an easy way to format it as a readable JSON file, with newlines and indentation?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) has three parameters, you can use third parameter for that

```
JSON.stringify(json, null, 4);
```