# How to download file in angularJS.For safari browser and edge browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari

I am new to angularJS.I want to download JSON file.It is working in chrome but not in Edge and Safari.In safari file is opening in browser only.
Thanks for reading.
Plz reply.

```
function itemExport() {
                    var a = document.createElement("a");
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    //a.style = "display: none";
                    if ($scope.selectedRows.length > 0) {
                        commonFactory.itemExport($scope.selectedRows, $scope.className).then(function (data) {

                            var json = JSON.stringify(data.data),
                                blob = new Blob([json], {type: "octet/stream"});
                                    //url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                            var encodedUri = encodeURI("data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + json);
                            a.setAttribute("href",encodedUri);
                            if ($scope.selectedRows.length === 1) {
                                commonFactory.getInstanceByUID($scope.domainUID, $scope.classUID, $scope.className, $scope.selectedRows[0], $scope.isCoreComponents).then(function (inst) {
                                    a.setAttribute("download", inst[0]._fields[0].properties.Name+".json");
                                    a.click();
                                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                                    });
                            } else {
                                a.download = $scope.className+".json";
                                a.click();
                                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        toastrFactory.warning('Please select at least one item to Export', 'Warning');
                    }
                }
```

Comment: A comment to the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30800715/1497533) says that this method does not work in internet explorer if the data is longer than 2000 characters. I would assume that you can't get around this, so you either have to shorten your data, or serve it from a server where you can set the headers.

Comment: @ippi-is it possible in safari?

Comment: If I knew the answer, I would make it an answer. For now it's mostly guesswork, but http://stackoverflow.com/q/417142/1497533 might be interesting, and https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js might even help.

Comment: @ippi- ok,Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I’m having the same issue.

Comment: @Brian I used [link](http://danml.com/download.html).it is working for edge browser,chrome but for safari need to do save As manually.