# Write json to file locally via browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, xojo

I have a requirement which i need some input on, I am using a very outdated version of xojo for a legacy application, the requirement is i need to open a webpage on the users system which isn't connected to the internet!

So i have a folder containing a website on its entirety, when i open the index.html file it loads all the resources locally and does not require anything to be download or access the internet.

Now on this website the user performs some actions like a survey or a guide as an example and i need to record all these actions and store it on a file so that later when the user is connected to the internet i can upload the files to the server.

How can i write json data to a file on the users pc via IE/Chrome/Firefox/Safari using javascript? Any ideas will be helpful.

Comment: Is there a reason they're not online, or is it just poor connectivity? There's typically no way to write a file to the file system directly from a browser (it's a bit of a security risk) without prompting them to download a file.

Comment: There is, they use this legacy application in a no internet environment at certain client locations, is there a way to write to a already existing file in the local folder where the html file is located?

Comment: Creating files and saving it in storage is a server side act. Your application is similar to browser itself. So it can not be done directly. You have to access server side resources of that device.

Comment: It sounds like you'd be better off writing a desktop application for your purposes.

Comment: you could possibly use an alternative mechanism like localStorage within the browser. But it will only end up being uploaded to the server if the user actually opens the same page again while connected to the net...and you might still have issues with things like CORS if it's not running in a proper http environment. You'd be better off with a proper thick-client app (i.e. desktop application) and maybe a background service to do the syncing

Comment: Putting the page into an electron app would be worth looking into

Comment: @charlietfl  electron would let me write to a file even though it uses js ?

Comment: Yes. It has internal node.js server and runs as desktop app

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks ill look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You can only emulate a download, direct writing to local disk is not allowed.

See this post for possible answer:

[Download JSON object as a file from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721439/download-json-object-as-a-file-from-browser)

Comment: So what your saying is i can use js to create a json object and have that downloaded to disk? will it require the user to manually save it to a location? or can i specify  the location to where the file has to be saved?

Comment: User will have to manually save it. Actually i just remembered my cousin had a similar case to yours, mentioned an issue where reading in files from local disk is not allowed either when running an html file out of a directory directly.
He created an SPA using Spring Framework as a service the user could run locally. https://spring.io/

Comment: I think he used Spring Boot https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot