# How to write to a JSON file in javascriptp?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, file

I am trying to write to a JSON file in a client side react web app. I have a nested object and I would like to be able to save this as a JSON file that a user can download.

Is this possible?

For example, here is my javascript object is:

```js
{
  summary: {
    totals: {
      apples: 3,
      oranges: 2,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download JSON object as a file from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721439/download-json-object-as-a-file-from-browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Tyler, it is very possible.

You need to make use of blobs to do that.

Here's a sample that downloads a file containing the text "I'm a ninja!" :

```js
let txt = "I'm a ninja"; // we all want to be one, don't we? ;)

let blob = new Blob([txt], {type: 'text/plain'});

// Only way to initiate a download is by clicking a download link,
// so let's make one
let ln = document.createElement('a');
ln.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
ln.download = 'ninja.txt';
ln.click(); // trigger the download

// Remove the blob url reference to free up memory
URL.revokeObjectURL(ln.href);
```

The only change you'd have to make is to replace `txt`'s content with a string version of the json by calling `JSON.stringify` on the object. Oh, and you should also change the file name to something like `data.json`.

You can learn more about blobs [here](https://javascript.info/blob).