# How to save JSON data to file

Tags: javascript

There is a JSON data stored in a variable in javascript. I have to stored it in other file named .json.How can I do it.Json data is something like this :

```
{
  "method":"get",
  "class":"form-horizontal",
  "html":[{
              "type":"div",
              "class":"form-group",
              "id":"input_Name",
              "html":[{
                       "type":"label",
                       "class":"control-label col-sm-2",
                       "for":"input_Name",
                       "html":"Name"},
                      {
                       "type":"div",
                       "class":"col-sm-10",
                       "html":[{
                               "type":"text",
                               "class":"form-control",
                               "name":"input_Name",
                               "id":"input_Name",
                               "placeholder":"user@example.com"
                              }]
                      }]
        }]
}
```

Comment: what do you want exactly?

Comment: There is a JSON data stored in a variable in javascript. I have to stored it in other file named .json.How can I do it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Save a file at client side using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080929/how-to-save-a-file-at-client-side-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Use `saveAs(blob, filename)` :

```
var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, "data.json");
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2wcew2xs/

Comment: Bevore saveAs(…) possible, you need to implement https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/ of course.